# Shloka regarding pradhāna and prakṛti

Tags: scripture, vedas, reference-request

I'm looking for the shloka which explains that there are two eternal principles: pradhāna or prakṛti.

Comment: By pradhana do you mean purusha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Srimad Bhagavatam 3.26.10

śrī-bhagavān uvāca
yat tat tri-guṇam avyaktaṁ
nityaṁ sad-asad-ātmakam
pradhānaṁ prakṛtiṁ prāhur
aviśeṣaṁ viśeṣavat

"The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: The unmanifested eternal combination of the three modes is the cause of the manifest state and is called pradhāna. It is called prakṛti when in the manifested stage of existence."

Comment: Dear Krsna prabhu, thank you so much(^o^). It solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

B G. 15.16 dvaimuh purushho lokkae shra akshara yeva cha
Shra saravani bhoothani kutaaskhara uchyathye

There 2 types purusha/soul/jiva one is destructible and another is non destructible. All destructible bootha/jiva reach sky as their destination.

Adhyatmic interpertation: 2 types of jiva are Normal souls other is Lakshmi who is consort of sriman Narayana and who is lord of prakruthi who is non destructive. Under normal circumstances all jiva reside inside her that kootashtha and she is abhimaani of sky also.

Note:
Destructible means one who can have multiple bodies which are destroyed
Non destructible  Jiva her body cannot be destroyed who never takes up destructible body like us

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, thank you. It helped my understanding(^o^).